# How to make an collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Actually i have this radio buttons in my rails app:

```
<%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, 'V' %>
<%= f.label :sicherheit, "Verdacht auf"%>
<%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, 'Z' %>
<%= f.label :sicherheit, "Zustand nach" %>
<%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, "A" %>
<%= f.label :sicherheit, "Ausschluss" %>
<%= f.radio_button :sicherheit, "G" %>
<%= f.label :sicherheit, "Gesicherte Diagnose" %>
```

I would like to change it to an collection select, but i dont know how to do it, i hope somebody can help me?

Comment: This doc should help: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select - if this doesn't help or if you have a specific question about the meaning of some portion of it, then please clarify which portion you're stumbling on. Good luck!

Comment: Of course i informed me before posting that question! But i couldnt figure it out! I hope you can help me

Comment: Does somebody have an solution without an gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this without any gem.

```
<%= f.select :sicherheit, [["Verdacht auf", "V"], ["Zustand nach", "Z"], ["Ausschluss", "A"], ["Gesicherte Diagnose", "G"]] %>
```

Comment: I think this is better than the `simple_form` solution since adding a dependency to your app just to create collection select seems like it's *really* over doing it.

Comment: <%= f.select :sicherheit, [["Verdacht auf", "V"], ["Zustand nach", "Z"], ["Ausschluss", "A"], ["Gesicherte Diagnose", "G"]], {}, {:class => "somehtmlclass"} %>

Answer (score 1):

**Rails way**:

```
<%= f.select :sicherheit, [["Verdacht auf", "V"], ["Zustand nach", "Z"], ["Ausschluss", "A"], ["Gesicherte Diagnose", "G"]] %>
```

Or if you prefer using **simple_form**:

First add `gem 'simple_form'` to your gemfile. Now run `bundle`

Do the following:

```
<%= f.input :sicherheit, collection: [["Verdacht auf", "V"], ["Zustand nach", "Z"], ["Ausschluss", "A"], ["Gesicherte Diagnose", "G"]] %>
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: I just noticed that you said "change it to a collection select" so I have removed "as: :radio_buttons"